# /Download JSON and only update if there is a change. Can Firebase do this?

Tags: json, database, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I plan on having a massive JSON, ~20MB, and I am creating a React Native App using the JSON. I want to have the app:

Download only the changes to the JSON.

or at least

Download only if changes have been made (which will be less than once a month).

If there is something better than Firebase I would be fine switching over to that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, a huge JSON object which change once a week. the way that I solved this issue is as following

lets say that we have an object O ~20MB

I created in my firebase db the object data = {raw: O, update: Date()}

on the client side I checked /data/update and compare it to the user localStorage. if it changed I replaced the user`s localstorage object, otherwise skipped.

In  this way you dont need to download the whole O only to fetch the date object

it looks like

```
const {update, raw} = localStorage.fetch('/data')
const last_update = firebase.fetch('/data/update')
if(update === last_update){return raw}
const new_raw = firebase.fetch('/data/raw')
localStorage.save('/data', {update: last_update, raw: new_raw})
return new_raw
```

Comment: How did you download the new data? It is too large for me to fetch using Firebase. Is there something else you used?

Comment: you can split the data i.e lets say you have 2 lists so download the first one and than the other, or iterate every one of them. in general, its a bad practice to download big amount of data to the client side and it sounds like you need a server side to manage your data :)